# Setting up winrm connections with dynamically created inventory group using ansible add_host module

Tags: ansible, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to establish WinRm connections to a set of windows machines to  automate a cloning task(windows vms) using ansible automation platform.
I populated an inventory group called cloned_group by passing some hostnames through the survey list option .But I continously get the following error when trying to run the task of establishing winrm connection( Staging Source VM (local admin user provision and WinRM HTTPS configuration)). The cloned_group is created successfully

The error takes the below pattern

```
<localhost> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<localhost> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: s@b.y on PORT 5986 TO localhost
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host localhost:
credssp: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5986): Max retries exceeded
with url: /wsman (Caused by
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
0x7f7e3f676640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection
refused'))
Using module file /usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/vmware/plugins/modules/vmware_vm_shell.py
Pipelining is enabled.
```

And the playbook is the following

```
name: Stage source vm
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files: 
    - common-vars.yml
  vars: 
    localusername: testlocal

  tasks:
    - name: Add host to the cloned group from the survey list 
      ansible.builtin.add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: cloned_group
      loop: [clone_machine_1, clone_machine_2, clone_machine_3]
    - debug:
        var: groups.cloned_group

          
    - name: Staging Source VM (local admin user provision and WinRM HTTPS configuration)
      community.vmware.vmware_vm_shell:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
        folder: "/{{ datacenter_name }}/vm/"
        vm_id: "{{ item }}"  # Use inventory_hostname as vm_id
        vm_id_type: "dns_name"
        vm_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        vm_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
        vm_shell: 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
        vm_shell_args: |
          winrm quickconfig -transport:https -Force;
          winrm set winrm/config/service '@{CertificateThumbprint=""}';
          New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'WinRm Https' -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 5986 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow
        vm_shell_cwd: 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop'
      loop: "{{ groups.cloned_group }}"
      register: staging
```